# Ignore overloaded methods in a composed object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Consider the following example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class ModelA {
  private ModelB modelB;
}
```

`ModelB` introduces two *overloaded* methods such as `setProperty(String)` and `setProperty(Object)`. This confuses Jackson's `ObjectMapper` complaining about "confliciting setter definitions":

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Conflicting setter definitions for property "property": ModelB#setProperty(1 params) vs ModelB#setProperty(1 params)
```

I'm aware that if I can use *inheritance* then I can use `@JsonIgnore` as in proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349204/248082). I'm also aware that a bottom-line solution would be to develop a custom Jackson deserializer (although very complex in my case). But, I'd like to know if there is a workaround for this if I'm restricted to use *composition*?