# Deserializing JSON into object with polymorphic setter methods using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize a JSON sent from a REST application. This object needs to be deserialized into a 3rd party object that contains polymorphic methods. When I attempt to do the deserialization using jackson I get the following exception:

> Conflicting setter definitions for property "system":
>   ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.composite.CodingDt#setSystem(1 params) vs
>   ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.composite.CodingDt#setSystem(1 params)

```
public CodingDt setSystem(UriDt theValue) {
    mySystem = theValue;
    return this;
}

public CodingDt setSystem( String theUri) {
    mySystem = new UriDt(theUri); 
    return this; 
}
```

I cannot modify the 3rd party class so used the Jackson MixIn as described in the ticket [Jackson Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346018/deserializing-json-into-object-with-overloaded-methods-using-jackson).This approach seems to work but there are many classes that this class refers to, that has the same exact problem. If I need to add a MixIn for each class, then I am ending up with a large number of MixIn's which is making the code less readable and hard to maintain.

Is there any global setting in Jackson that I can set, so that only one of the setters is used, or a setting to provide additional info to the deserailizer so that it does not complain.

Comment: Have try deserialisation using fields instead of setters? Something like this https://gist.github.com/bhdrkn/d53f15858dd304b33542

Comment: I cannot use fields as the field name is different to the getter/setter.

Comment: If your only concern is about field name, you may try both using fields and a propertyNamingStrategy and map existing fields with your liking. Here an example for PropertyNamingStrategy, http://www.javaroots.com/2013/03/how-to-use-naming-in-jackson.html

Comment: I think thats what I want.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use the PropertyNamingStrategy for Jackson as described in 
http://www.javaroots.com/2013/03/how-to-use-naming-in-jackson.html. Thanks to @bhdrkn

I also have to use the following code to ignore unknown properties for my code to work.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```