# Ignore setters with argument type using Jackson mixIn

Tags: java, jackson

I have a 3rd party jar library with some POJOs.
I want to deserialize them with jackson.

Some of the fields have a double setter, like:

```
public void setValue(Value value) {
    this.value = value.getValue();
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

These setters cause `jackson` to throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property ...`.

Currently I'm ignoring one setter at a time using jackson mixin, but there are so many of these setters that I'm writing as much code as the actual POJO at this point.

Is there a way to ignore ALL setters that have an argument of type `Value`?

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. This works for me. Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON into object with overloaded methods using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346018/deserializing-json-into-object-with-overloaded-methods-using-jackson)

Comment: Do you use [fasterxml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) implementation or [codehaus](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson)?